# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: 8192

Tags: error, php, embeds

I have some php code that I have embedded. Which seems to work fine alone on the server however when embedded I get this error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: Function split() is deprecated

Filename: libraries/Functions.php(679) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 221
```

How do I go about correcting this error?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the split method in you php code, you shouldn't. If you see on the [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php), the split method is being deprecated. You should use one of the alternate functions listed there.

If you aren't trying to use regular expressions, you should probably just use the [explode method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).